# How to calculate the gradient of $c^Tx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to compute the gradient vector for $f(x)=c^Tx$.

$c,x\space\in\space\mathbb{R}^n$ and are two $n\times 1$ column vectors.

It's been so long since I've done this I don't whow where to start and all the reference material I have found online uses polynomials with gradients instead of vectors. How would I go about computing this?

Comment: the gradient is $c^T$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{c}=(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ then 
$$
\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})=(c_1,\dots,c_n)=\vec{c}
$$

Comment: So differentiating a function where x is a vector still returns the same result?

Comment: @user1362058 It is just that this function $f$ is linear.

Comment: Mistake in the comment. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an exterior definition of $\nabla f$ through differential, namely

$df = \nabla f^T \cdot dx$, but

$df = c^T \cdot dx$, hence

$\nabla f = c$.

This works for much much more complex expression, incl. matrices, which would become a real pain, using the interior definition

Comment: I found some more  info on the exterior when I was looking up the gradient of the quadratic equation. Thanks.